# Kingo Root - require networkconnection

Tags: rooting

I would like to know why Kingo Root wants networkconnection when one clicks the "one click"-root button? I read a thread on XDA-forum that you could disable network-connection during root to protect things to be transmitted to a remote server (important data such as the EFS-folder).

So - Is there any reason the app wants me to be connected to internet when rooting? Should I be worried?

Comment: This should be easier to be answered if you asked the developer themselves, but... [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2527977) had this suspicion before, and they *seem* to take an action by removing the app from there, until it's proven that it doesn't contain any malware (read: sending private data). If you're still unable to root your device without internet connection, then you've been warned, since the rooting process itself shouldn't need internet.

Comment: Simple alternative is to go for a trusted root app like Framaroot. The root process is pretty simple in Kingo Root, I agree, but I would definitely prefer a confirmed working app over it any day.